# Following a question

Tags: support, questions

Hi,

Is there a way to "subscribe"/ follow an interesting question without replying to it?

Best regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can click the star icon to tag it as a "favorite", it will then appear on your favorites list on your profile page where you can access them.

I know some users do this, but I personally prefer to just bookmark them.

Comment: When answers are posted on favorite questions, you will also receive a notification.

Comment: @BloodPhilia thank you very much for this addition. This was exactly what I was hoping to learn. :)

Answer (score 5):

Every question also has an RSS feed. You can follow in whatever your favorite feed reader is.

For instance, the RSS feed for this question is

`http://meta.superuser.com/feeds/question/1563`